# FFmpeg drawtext issue when apply hindi language font file or other language font file

Tags: ffmpeg, custom-font, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

We are trying to use FFmpeg draw text to support Hindi fonts. but some characters are not rendering properly.

Used Hindi Language Font file :-https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Khula

```
Input string :- **जिन्दगी सिर्फ हकीक़त है हकीक़त समझो,**
```

But output renders as
[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ5Xw.png)

I want some perfect solution to apply assets font on `FFmpeg.`

**Thank you in Advance.**

Comment: I wonder if ASS subtitles and the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) has better support for Hindi.

Comment: Hii, llogon but We do not use subtitles filter , use drawtext

Comment: If you must use drawtext then you should ask the authors of libfreetype about the rendering issue, as libfreetype is the library that drawtext depends on.